# Django: How to redirect UpdateView in the get request

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a use-case in which if a drop-down changes, the view should be redirected to another view.  In the update view, I am using built-in class-based view, `UpdateView`.  How do I redirect if the redirect is needed before submitting the form.  I take it that [get_success_url()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.get_success_url) works for when the form is submitted

Comment: To redirect on the dropdown check, you can use JS. First, detect the dropdown change by js then redirect to your desired URL.

Comment: That's a fair work-around.  But, I remember I did that by overriding the ```get()``` method in the CBV. Now, I am not able to fully remember how exactly and thought there is a one-liner that would do that.  Plus, I generally like to have a two-layer approach, so if the front-end failed for whatever reason, the backend covers it

Answer (score 0):

So, here is how I made it work:

```
class MyUpdateView(UpdateView):

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        get_return = super(MyUpdateView, self).get(*args, **kwargs)
        context = self.get_context_data( **kwargs)

        if context.get('redirect_url'):
            return HttpResponseRedirect(context.get('redirect_url'))
        return get_return

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        selected_project_id = self.request.GET.get('project_selector', None)  

        if selected_project_id:
            namespace     = 'project'
            redirect_url  = 'update-project'
            redirect_url  = reverse('{namespace}:{url}'.format(namespace = namespace, url = redirect_url), kwargs = {'pk': selected_project_id} )
            context['redirect_url'] = redirect_url
        ...
        return context
```

Basically, redirect should occur inside the get method of CBV. I did try it inside `get_context_data`, but Django complains that `get_context_data` is only supposed to return a dict and not `HttpResponseRedirect`. So, I am interrupting the get request, look at the context, and if the context is loaded with a `selected_project_id`, the view redirects to the `update-project` for the selected project